# Setup Crashlytics without Eclipse plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, jenkins, ant, crashlytics

The main issue we're having is getting Ant to prepare the build_id (described in com_crashlytics_export_string.xml) so that our app doesn't crash on start with the following message "This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up".

Now we have a Jenkins setup that is building the app without the use of any IDE and therefore no Fabric plugin. Is there any way to supply/create the build_id without the plugin to prevent the crash?

Comment: If you would use android studio with a gradle build config then you could just disable crashlytics for a certain build type / product flavor and use that for your jenkins build. Otherwise you can just catch that exception.

Comment: we plan on getting it to work on android studio but we're still mainly using eclipse and this is the last hurdle it seems to get this working so we'd rather finish this and when the times comes im sure it will be less of a headache in studio